# Directing traffic via proxy for one domain only

Tags: networking, internet, proxy, redirection

I want traffic to a specific secure website(***.facebook.com**) to go through a Proxy server and port - 192.168.34.34 on port 1818

Now, I know under Internet Options, you can specify a proxy address, but then all traffic will go through that Proxy. I want to direct traffic ONLY to *.facebook.com to go through the proxy.

Do you perhaps set this in the hosts file like this:

```
192.168.34.34 1818 *facebook.com
```

Don't think this works however. How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a workaround than a straight answer to your need.. but why not use a separate browser for that specific reason?

You can use Firefox set up with Proxy. Yes it will route ALL Firefox (not all traffic, just those from Firefox) traffic via the proxy. But then you can have firefox only for *.facebook.com and use other browser for all other purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah thanks, know how to do it with FF, thought there might be a more universal and easier way(as to adding a group policy for it) way than Firefox